# Counting the number of returning item for a timeframe

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

#### Context:

For every item returned, we need to know how many time "this" item was return in different timeframe: 30,60,90,120,180,365 days.

An item is unique based on his Serial (`Itm_Item_Serial`).

#### Sample Data:

Complete sample with creation script, and expected result [here](http://rextester.com/XTAW47180)*.

```
CREATE TABLE ItemReturn
(
     [Itm_Id] int, 
     [Itm_Item_Serial] int, 
     [Itm_CDate] datetime
);

INSERT INTO ItemReturn ([Itm_Id], [Itm_Item_Serial], [Itm_CDate])
VALUES       
    (1, 1, '2016-10-02 02:00:00'),
    (2, 1, '2016-09-03 02:00:00'),
    (3, 1, '2016-11-03 01:00:00')   
;
```

#### Expected result: for Itm_Item_Serial = 1

```
Itm_Id    30d    60d    90d    120d    180d    365d
1          0      0      0      0       0        0
2          1      0      0      0       0        0
3          1      1      0      0       0        0
```

0 or null if there is no return in this time frame.

#### How does it work: for Itm_Item_Serial = 1

```
[Itm_Id]  [Itm_Item_Serial] [Itm_CDate] 
1,         1,               '2016-10-02 02:00:00'
2,         1,               '2016-09-03 02:00:00'
3,         1,               '2016-11-03 01:00:00'
```

- For [Itm_Id]=1, there is 0 previous return.
- For [Itm_Id]=2, there is 1 previous return

  - on '2016-10-02'. datediff = 29. So there is one return in the timeframe "0-30 Days".
- For [Itm_Id]=3, there is 2 previous return.

  - on '2016-09-03'. datediff = 60. So there is one return in the timeframe "30-60 Days".
  - on '2016-10-02'. datediff = 31. So there is one return in the timeframe "30-60 Days".

*: rextester Data Sample, and ordered Data Sample.

Comment: plus 1 for sample data,can you also paste expected output for the the data sample you gace

Comment: You could use conditional aggregration for each of the columns so that `sum(case when m1.item_Cdate >DATEADD(DAY,-30,m.Itm_CDate) then 1 else 0 end)` and repeat in 6 different cases.  but you have to ask is each group exclusive of the other if it's in 30 it does it show in 60?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Have a fiddle ready...just need to know what the "expected" result should be.

Comment: Ok, do it via Pivot

Comment: 30 days from which date?

Comment: @DragandDrop thank you for your response....understand we will not give you the answer....we will help you along the path to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/00460/4

Does not give you the result you provided but does provide the counts for the various day lapses

```
; with data_CTE as (
    select
        m1.Itm_CDate
        , DATEDIFF(day, m1.Itm_CDate, m2.Itm_CDate) DayDiff
        , m1.Itm_id
        , m1.Itm_Item_Serial
    from ItemReturn m1
        left outer join ItemReturn m2
            on m1.Itm_Item_Serial = m2.Itm_Item_Serial
    where m1.Itm_CDate < m2.Itm_CDate
        and m1.Itm_CDate > DATEADD(day, -30, m2.Itm_CDate)
), aggr_CTE as (
    select 
        Itm_Id, Itm_Item_Serial
        , case 
            when DayDiff < 30 then '30d'
            when DayDiff < 60 then '60d'
            when DayDiff < 90 then '90d'
            when DayDiff < 120 then '120d'
            when DayDiff < 180 then '180d'
            else '365d'
        end DayLapse
    from data_CTE
)select 
    Itm_id, [30d], [60d], [90d], [120d], [180d], [365d]
from (
    select Itm_id, Itm_Item_Serial, DayLapse
    from aggr_CTE
) src PIVOT (
    count(Itm_Item_Serial)
    for DayLapse in ([30d], [60d], [90d], [120d], [180d], [365d])
) as PivotTable
```

`data_CTE` Result (Output):

```
Itm_CDate               DayDiff     Itm_id      Itm_Item_Serial
----------------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------
2016-09-03 02:00:00.000 29          2           1
2016-09-03 02:00:00.000 29          3           1
2016-09-03 02:00:00.000 29          5           2
2016-09-03 02:00:00.000 29          13          6
2016-08-05 02:00:00.000 29          15          6
2016-08-04 02:00:00.000 1           14          6
```

### Update: 2017-07-26

Final Version of the Query

```
; with data_CTE as ( 
     SELECT 
     Itm_Id 
     , Itm_Item_Serial 
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition By Itm_Item_Serial order by Itm_Item_Serial) Itm_Item_RowNum 
     , Itm_CDate 
     FROM [ItemReturn] ir1 
 ), date_CTE as (
    select 
        d2.Itm_Id
        , d1.Itm_Item_Serial
        , DATEDIFF(day, d1.Itm_CDate, d2.Itm_CDate) DayDiff
     from data_CTE d1, data_CTE d2
     where d1.Itm_Item_Serial = d2.Itm_Item_Serial
        and DATEDIFF(day, d1.Itm_CDate, d2.Itm_CDate) >= 0
), aggr_CTE as (
    select 
        Itm_Id, Itm_Item_Serial
        , case 
            when DayDiff <= 0 then '0d'
            when DayDiff <= 30 then '30d'
            when DayDiff <= 60 then '60d'
            when DayDiff <= 90 then '90d'
            when DayDiff <= 120 then '120d'
            when DayDiff <= 180 then '180d'
            else '365d'
        end DayLapse
    from date_CTE
)select 
    Itm_id, [30d], [60d], [90d], [120d], [180d], [365d]
from (
    select Itm_id, Itm_Item_Serial, DayLapse
    from aggr_CTE
) src PIVOT (
    count(Itm_Item_Serial)
    for DayLapse in ([0d], [30d], [60d], [90d], [120d], [180d], [365d])
) as PivotTable
```

Comment: Tweak the `data_CTE` for data acquisition and data window

Comment: Nope, I modeled it into my SQL Ent environment and most of the dates are 365d

Comment: At best with `Date - 30`, you should have a 90d value for `Itm_id`=16

Comment: Modify the `data_CTE` query to acquire the data you require.  Only the data-set, not the manipulation patterns

Comment: @DragandDrop this is probably closer to your needs, as a result

Comment: @DragandDrop if you can get the `DayDiff` values you need into the `data_CTE` section, similar to the format I have shown.  The rest of the structure will perform the result you require.  The critical key is obtaining the `DayDiff` value you need.  The best approach is to keep the `source` table with as few columns needed.  Then transform the key values in the `DayDiff` column into their own distinct Columns (30d, 60d, etc) and apply Count you require.

Answer (score 1):

You can query as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select Itm_id, Itm_Item_Serial, case when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, getdate()) between  0 and 30 then '30'
               when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, getdate()) between 30 and 60 then '60'
               when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, getdate()) between 60 and 90 then '90'
               when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, getdate()) between 90 and 120 then '120'
               when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, getdate()) between 120 and 180 then '180'
               when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, getdate()) between 180 and 360 then '365' 
                Else 0 End as test              
             from ItemReturn
) a
pivot (count(test) for test in ([30],[60],[90],[120],[180],[365])) p
```

If your difference date is between next date then you might need to use lead as below:

```
;With cte as (
    Select *, NextDate = lead(itm_cDate) over(partition by Itm_Item_Serial order by Itm_id) 
        from ItemReturn
    ), cte2 as (
    Select Itm_id, Itm_Item_Serial, case when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, NextDate) between  0 and 30 then '30'
                when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, NextDate) between 30 and 60 then '60'
                when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, NextDate) between 60 and 90 then '90'
                when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, NextDate) between 90 and 120 then '120'
                when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, NextDate) between 120 and 180 then '180'
                when datediff(day, Itm_CDate, NextDate) between 180 and 360 then '365' 
                Else 0 End as test              
                from cte
    )
    Select * from cte2 
    pivot (count(test) for test in ([30],[60],[90],[120],[180],[365])) p
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/HTMR24987) here

Answer (score 1):

not the final answer but slick way to get the difference

```
with cte as 
select [Itm_Id], [Itm_Item_Serial], [Itm_CDate] 
     , row_number() over (partition by [Itm_Item_Serial] order by [Itm_CDate]) as rn
from ItemReturn;
select t1.*
     , datediff(dd, t1.[Itm_CDate], t2.[Itm_CDate] desc) as diff 
     , t2.[Itm_Id], t2.[Itm_CDate]
 from cte t1 
 join cte t2 
   on t1.[Itm_Item_Serial] = t2.[Itm_Item_Serial] 
  and t1.rn = 1 
  and t2.rn <> 1
order by t1.[Itm_Item_Serial], t1.rn
```